# Prevent .load() overwrite my html?

Tags: javascript, ajax, load

In my main html file I'm trying to load few other html files with `id="contentToLoad"`.
All the loaded html will append to `id="allWrapper"` inside my main.html file.

```
$(function () {
  for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $('#allWrapper').load('htmlFile' + i + '.html #contentToLoad', function () {
      $(this).appendTo('#allWrapper')
      //alert('Load was performed.');
    });
  }
});
```

One problem I encountered is that each newly added html content will overwrite by the previous one. How do I display all of them without overwriting each html file?

Comment: If this question is resolved, please select the answer that worked as such. Having a selected answer lets others know which solution worked for you quickly without reading comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
{

    $.get('htmlFile' + i + '.html #contentToLoad', function(data){
      $(data).appendTo('#allWrapper') 
    });

}

});

</script>
```

Comment: but I not sure why it is loading my entire html(meta and title) instead of just #conttentToLoad div though.....

Answer (score 0):

That's how load works, try using $.get instead.

```
for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
    $.get('htmlFile' + i + '.html', function(data) {
        $(data).find('#contentToLoad').appendTo('#allWrapper') 
        //alert('Load was performed.');
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried replacing my code with your but still doesnt work??

Answer (score 0):

The point of the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method is to insert the HTML from the GET request into the DOM element you've selected.

What you'll want to use is the [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method, especially as how it's used in the first example in the jQuery docs:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('#allWrapper').append($(data).find('#contentToLoad'));
});
```

Comment: I have try your method but how come the html still not showing?

Answer (score 0):

Try storing it to a variable and appending that variable to whatever container you want

```
var mycode = $('<div></div>');

mycode.load('htmlFile' + i + '.html #contentToLoad', function() {
    var x = mycode.html();
    $('#allWrapper').append(x);
});
```

try that.

Comment: nope, it doesnt work, it stills  overwrite my previous html and show me the last html file only